# Mysql slow query with lots of joins

Tags: mysql

I have got the query operating on rather small tables (most of 4000 rows each). THe query lasts about 4 seconds and contains several joins, however, all joins use indexes.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT p0_.id) AS sclr0 
FROM promoter p0_ 
LEFT JOIN user u1_ ON p0_.user_id = u1_.id 
LEFT JOIN profile p2_ ON p0_.id = p2_.promoter_id 
LEFT JOIN promoter_city p4_ ON p0_.id = p4_.user_id 
LEFT JOIN city c3_ ON c3_.id = p4_.city_id 
LEFT JOIN promoter_language p6_ ON p0_.id = p6_.user_id 
LEFT JOIN language l5_ ON l5_.id = p6_.language_id 
LEFT JOIN promoter_worker_type p8_ ON p0_.id = p8_.promoter_id 
LEFT JOIN worker_type w7_ ON w7_.id = p8_.workertype_id 
LEFT JOIN practise p9_ ON p0_.id = p9_.promoter_id 
LEFT JOIN contract c11_ ON p0_.id = c11_.promoter_id
```

And here is the output of the explain:

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        id        |   select_type    |      table       |       type       |  possible_keys   |       key        |     key_len      |       ref        |       rows       |      Extra       |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        1         |      SIMPLE      |       p0_        |      index       |                  |UNIQ_BCB929A3A76ED|        5         |                  |       4161       |   Using index    |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        1         |      SIMPLE      |       u1_        |      eq_ref      |     PRIMARY      |     PRIMARY      |        4         |promoteri.p0_.user|        1         |   Using index    |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        1         |      SIMPLE      |       p2_        |       ref        |type,IDX_8157AA0F4|       type       |        5         | promoteri.p0_.id |        1         |   Using index    |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        1         |      SIMPLE      |       p4_        |       ref        |PRIMARY,IDX_183C53|     PRIMARY      |        4         | promoteri.p0_.id |        1         |   Using index    |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        1         |      SIMPLE      |       c3_        |      eq_ref      |     PRIMARY      |     PRIMARY      |        4         |promoteri.p4_.city|        1         |   Using index    |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        1         |      SIMPLE      |       p6_        |       ref        |PRIMARY,IDX_19EE2A|     PRIMARY      |        4         | promoteri.p0_.id |        1         |   Using index    |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        1         |      SIMPLE      |       l5_        |      eq_ref      |     PRIMARY      |     PRIMARY      |        4         |promoteri.p6_.lang|        1         |   Using index    |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        1         |      SIMPLE      |       p8_        |       ref        |PRIMARY,IDX_37AC17|     PRIMARY      |        4         | promoteri.p0_.id |        1         |   Using index    |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        1         |      SIMPLE      |       w7_        |      eq_ref      |     PRIMARY      |     PRIMARY      |        4         |promoteri.p8_.work|        1         |   Using index    |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        1         |      SIMPLE      |       p9_        |       ref        |IDX_352E261F4B84B2|IDX_352E261F4B84B2|        5         | promoteri.p0_.id |        1         |   Using index    |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        1         |      SIMPLE      |       c11_       |       ref        |IDX_E98F28594B84B2|IDX_E98F28594B84B2|        5         | promoteri.p0_.id |        6         |   Using index    |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I do know, that the JOINS are unnecessary in this query, however I use lot of similar queries having some where statements applied, where it really matters to have these joins.

Is there any explanation, why this query takes so long?

Comment: In the other queries that have columns in the `WHERE` clause from the joined tables... do you still use `LEFT JOIN`, or do those queries use `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: The other queries look same, just have some where statements added. But it changes nothing on the fact, that this query, having no where at all, takes 4 seconds to execute.

Comment: Do the other queries also have a count(*)?

Comment: All queries have `count(DISTINCT p0_.id)` .

Comment: @SamuelHapak Trying changing all of those `left joins` to `inner joins`.  When you use `left join`, you force the optimizer to join the tables in the sequence you've provided... when you use `inner join`, the optimizer has the option of picking a better starting position for joining the tables.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson Thanks, the inner join improved the performance rapidly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing all of those `left joins` to `inner joins`. When you use `left join`, you force the optimizer to join the tables in the sequence you've provided... when you use `inner join`, the optimizer has the option of picking a better starting position for joining the tables.

As far as a reference for `left join` forcing a specific read order - from the [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html):

> The table read order forced by `LEFT JOIN` or `STRAIGHT_JOIN` helps the
>   join optimizer do its work much more quickly, because there are fewer
>   table permutations to check.

... Indicating that `left join` forces read order the same as `STRAIGHT_JOIN`.

Comment: Hi, I'm curious how you found this out?

Comment: @Bijan I added a reference to the MySQL docs that mentions `left join` forcing read order... there's probably a more direct reference to this, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Question about this.  With removing left join, wouldnt that mean records with a null for the id would no longer return?

Comment: @TravisB Yes, that's right.  Switching `left join` to `inner join` can change the number of rows returned... so it really depends on the specific scenario.